# How can I make my old Dbase 2 progs run under SQL?

Tags: sql-server, dbase

How can I make my old Dbase 2 progs run under SQL?

I want to do two things.

1. have my old Dbase progs run under windows with huge datasets on my personal computer (so it would have no internet need)

and
2. Have my old dbase progs run from an sql server on the internet where I could log on form the internet and work the program and database.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.harbour-project.org/, maybe it can run your application without modifications.